# Regular expressions exclusive or

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a section of regular expression where it accepts either word characters or numbers, but not both (exclusive or).

Right now I have:

```
[\w\d]+
```

To represent a word that is made of either digits or letters/underscores. But that still lets things like 5x and 143243243243242323a pass through, because technically they are letters or numbers. I have tried things like `[\w]+|[\d]+` but it has not worked for me so far. Any help?

Comment: What is a `word character` for you?

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches the words you described:

```
/^(?:[a-z_]+|\d+)$/i
```

If you don't want to match the underscore, simply remove it:

```
/^(?:[a-z]+|\d+)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattern:** `^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d+)$`

---

You were already on the right track with `[\w]+|[\d]+`. The problem was that the anchors `^` (matching at the beginning of the string) and `$` (matching at the end of the string) were missing. They make sure that there's nothing before or after `\w+` or `\d+`, thus ensuring the word **only** consists of either word characters or digits, but not a mixture of both (or any other character). Also, as Gergo pointed out, `\w` also matches digits.

The above pattern could also be written as the following, if that's clearer to you:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$|^\d+$
```

Comment: @GergoErdosi Of course, I was being stupid. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+`

To add boundary, like start of string and end `^[a-zA-Z_]+$|^[0-9]+$`

if you want grouping, use it as `([a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+)`

For non-capturing group use `(?:[a-zA-Z_]+|[0-9]+)`